# Make JTable scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jscrollbar

I'm trying to create a JTable with 2 columns, one must show the name of the product, the second one, the price. The problem is that the JTable is very small, so i need a scroll, but i can't create it.

[image]

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable productos = new JTable(model);


    model.addColumn("Product");//name of the first columns
    model.addColumn("Price");//name of the second columns
    BTW: the table doesn't show the name of the column, but creates the 2 columns


    for (i=0; i<null_copy4; i++)//null_copy4 is a integer that shows me how many stacks are used in the array
    {
        model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{product_copy3[i],price_copy3[i]});
    }
           //product_copy3 and price_copy3 are arrays. String[] and integer[].
    products.setBounds(5,50,200,200); //define the dimensions of the JTable
    this.add(productos);//add it to the window
```

Comment: If Tim Bender's suggestion helped you, don't forget to "accept" his answer.

Comment: On StackOverflow, instead of editing the title to say "(solved)" the OP usually "accepts" an answer. This will mark the question as being answered (answer count shows in gold). If you solve your own problem, then you can answer your own question and accept that answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about wrapping it in a [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)?